# PullToRefreshListView and getItemAtPosition

Tags: android

I'm trying to use PullToRefreshListView instead my standard ListView however, it did not work for me as a beginner, the listView is using an adapter and inflating xml item file into the listview,

when i replaced my listview wih

```
 </com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView>
```

the listview becomes empty, no items are loaded

- onItemClickListener()

when i replace the listview from ListView to PullToRefreshListView, i don't get the getItemAtPosition option,

so how can i add an onItemClickListener() if i can't get the position?

- list_fragment.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

         <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
              android:id="@+id/CarsList"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

      </LinearLayout>
  ```

  - my Activity.xml extends Activity

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncCallBack {

```
PullToRefreshListView           myList;
CustomList                      cl;

....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myList = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.CarsList);
    ...
```

That's the part of the code... getApiJsonArray is a listener which gets excuted on onPostExecute()

```
@Override
public JSONArray getApiJsonArray(JSONArray results) {
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    ArrayList<CarsItems> carsItems;
    try {
        carsItems = getCarsList(results);
        cl = new CustomList(this, carsItems);
        myList.setAdapter(cl);
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
```

Comment: there is a bug into `PullToRefreshListView` its adding element at top into listview adapter so the adapter length will be +1  so to request item position call it like this `position-1` , for example `myarray.get(position-1)`;

Comment: @JackKFouani but when i replaced the standard listview with the pulllistview no items are being loaded into my list anyway. the list becomes blank.... i'm confused..

Comment: can you post your full code please ? ill fix it to you :)

Comment: @JackKFouani added codes

Comment: have u tried `cl.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you add the elements to `carsItems` ?

Comment: @JackKFouani still empty, i added it after the setAdapter, and before the setAdapter... but no success

Comment: And i cannot see that the pulllist is loading anyway, since it's not adding any header, does it mean it's not loaded ?

Comment: if pulltorefresh header added then its ok , the problem is maybe your list is empty , try to do that in my answer in few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is in dimensions, the fill_parent is the problem, i check and it worked

By default when you copy and paste the pulltorefresh code into your project you get this :

```
<com.markupartist.android.widget.PullToRefreshListView
     android:id="@+id/android:list"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
/>
```

i hesitated to ask someone on stackoverflow cuz i frustrated with importing it and updating the support version.....etc

however when you copy the code directly into your project you get a blank list or no list at all

simply change the height and width to something else like match_parent, this should be a straight forward answer for beginners like me.

and if you get a problem not finding the getItemAtPosition() for the setOnItemClickListener() method in the list try to call it inside that method (the setOnItemClickListener())

like that

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        Object item = a.getItemAtPosition(position);
        ..
```

hope this will help beginners like me! :)

Comment: It would help others with the same problem if you could elaborate a bit. ie Specifically what about `fill_parent` was the problem and how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try to trace your code

```
Log.i("MyApp","Results = "+results.toString());
carsItems = getCarsList(results);
```

inside `CustomList` after you set the items inside the adapter add 
`notifyDataSetChanged();` <-- without this no elements will appear

Comment: results are there, if i revert to standard ListView it works fine.

Comment: i really have a feeling that the pulllistview isn't working anyway, since the area where the list is is completely blank, no interactions at all.

Comment: oh damn, my bad, it seems that the listview wasn't showing cuz of dimensions issue!, now it works fine :)

Comment: All working now, even the onClickListener! thank you alot @Jack